# Product Report Type No Results in Community Site

Tags: reporting

I am trying to get a Product report type to show in a community site. The profile this user is under has access to the object and the fields on the report. They also have access to the folder and the report. At first I was seeing insufficient privileges.

[image: insufficientprivileges.PNG]

So in the sharing settings, I changed the Product object from Public Read/Write to Private.

[image]

After changing to Private, the error message disappeared but getting no results.

[image]

So at this point, I try to create a sharing rule for this group on the Product, but I can only create rules based on criteria only for users (see image below)

And there are only a few amount of users in the dropdown for selection. The one I need is not in the dropdown, so I can't even test if the sharing rule is the issue for the report not showing any results.

[image]

How can I get the Product Sharing Rule to show like this where I can share by public groups (shown in image below)? Is there something I need to turn on in settings? Or is this the way it is currently for the Product object, and is there a way to get my user into the dropdown for selection?

[image]

Will the report show any results at all with the sharing rule? Do I need to go a different route?

Thank you for taking the time to read and answer. Much appreciated!